# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying single page application in which when I try to archive the mail it is showing error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier". I want to change archive button change between archive and unarchive.

here is my function for load mail

```
function load_mail(mail){
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#compose-error').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('emails-view-i').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('emails-view-headline').innerHTML = "";
  id = mail.id;
  console.log(mail);
  fetch(`/emails/${id}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(email => {
      // Print email
      const emailv = document.createElement('div');
      emailv.setAttribute("style","padding:10px");
      emailv.innerHTML = (`<p><strong> From: </strong> ${email.sender} </p><p><strong> To :</strong> ${email.recipients}</p><p><strong> Subject: </strong> ${email.subject}</p><p><strong> Timestamp: </strong>${email.timestamp}</p><hr><p>${email.body}</p>`);
      document.querySelector('#emails-view-i').append(emailv);
      const but1 = document.createElement('button');
      but1.setAttribute("type", 'button');
      //but1.setAttribute("name", `${email.id}`);
      but1.setAttribute("class", 'btn btn-outline-success');
      but1.setAttribute("id",'archive');
      m = `${email.archived}`;
      console.log(m);
      if (m == 'true'){
        but1.innerHTML = 'Unarchive';
      }
      else {
        but1.innerHTML = 'Archive';
      }
      but1.setAttribute("onclick", `change_archive(${email})`);
      document.querySelector('#emails-view-i').append(but1);
      const but2 = document.createElement('button');
      but2.setAttribute("type", 'button');
      but2.setAttribute("class", 'btn btn-outline-success');
      but2.innerHTML = 'Reply';
      but2.setAttribute("id",'reply');
      document.querySelector('#emails-view-i').append(but2);

      console.log(email);

      // ... do something else with email ...
  });
  fetch(`/emails/${id}`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        read: true
    })
  })

}
```

and function for archive

```
function change_archive(maili){
  console.log(maili);
  id = `${maili.id}`;
  //console.log(maili.archived);
  if (`${maili.archived}` == 'false'){
    document.getElementById('archive').innerHTML = 'Unarchive';
    fetch(`/emails/${id}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify({
          archived: true
      })
    })
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('archive').innerHTML = 'Archive';
    fetch(`/emails/${id}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify({
          archived: false
      })
    })
  }
}
```

HTML code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Mail</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/mail/styles.css">
        
    <script src="/static/mail/inbox.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            
    <h2>soham@example.com</h2>

    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="inbox">Inbox</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="compose">Compose</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="sent">Sent</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="archived">Archived</button>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" href="/logout">Log Out</a>
    <hr>

    <div id="emails-view">
      <div id="emails-view-headline"></div>
      <div id="emails-view-i"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="compose-view">
        <h3>New Email</h3>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="compose-error">
          <div id = "compose-error-i">
          </div>
        </div>
        <form id="compose-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                From: <input disabled class="form-control" value="soham@example.com">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                To: <input id="compose-recipients" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="compose-subject" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="compose-body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" id="compose-submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </form>
    </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't know why I am getting this error. please help!

Comment: Can you post the entire error. It would be good to know what line it refers to.

Comment: it is showing only this much

Comment: Neither of the two functions you posted cause a syntax error.

Comment: In chrome you can often expand the exception to see the stack trace. It will also show a link to what line it is on the right.

Comment: it is tracing to first line of HTML which is blank

Comment: Could you link your HTML page, not just the template above but the actual generated HTML?

Comment: changed it to actual generated HTML

Comment: Sorry but cant seem to reproduce